# Onion Architecture - Domain Model methods that require information from Infrastructure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm just getting started with DDD and implementing the Onion Architecture.

I'm making an invitation system, where a super user can invite another user by email to his company. However when creating the invitation, I want to ensure that the user is not already created in the system. I want to do that by checking if there's any record in the database with that email. I'm using Entity Framework to handle the database context.

And I've made a repository for both Invitation and UserAccount, that contain methods to find items based on an Id.

I need to use the DB context in order to see if the invitation is still valid, but since the method is declared in the Domain Layer, I can't really figure out how to do it, without breaking the design pattern. The Domain layer should not know anything about the persistence layer.

[image]

I thought about injecting the IUserAccountRepository and then executing the required methods in order to complete the Accept() method, but I'm afriad this is wrong.

Comment: `DeriveAccount` *must* throw an exception if it can't create an account because the user already exists.  Do you really need another redundant, *unreliable* check for that?

Answer (score 1):

> The Domain layer should not know anything about the persistence layer.

That's right - the domain layer should not know about persistence.

But that constraint doesn't apply to the *application layer*.

In other words, we design our domain model interface so that it "asks for" the information that we (might) need to successfully compute the next state of the model, and the application has the problem of figuring out where that information comes from.

```
public UserAccount Accept(Guid userId, Boolean userExistsInDatabase)
```

What you will see in some designs, is that instead of passing in the answer to the question, we'll pass in the capability of asking the question, and let the model decide for itself whether the question should be asked and what to do with the answer

```
public UserAccount Accept(Guid userId, Roster roster)
```

In this case, `Roster` would be an interface defined by your model, that accepts some piece of information that the model already has and reports back some other piece of information that your model understands.  Then your application would provide an implementation of this interface when invoking the method.

[Passing values across the boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) is a bit more "pure", in that the model code doesn't need to know anything about the failure modes of the Roster -- all of *that* code would instead live in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to use Contracts in your Domain Services.

"IUserAccountRepository"  is a Contract that we create in the domain and the domain service doesn't know about implementation.

So Do not worry about that it's right